# Configuring Impala log4j.properties

Tags: logging, log4j, impala

Where/how does impala look for a log4j.properties file?
How should we configure/pass -Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/log4j.properties for imapala?

I'm trying to set various classes logs to different level by configuring impala log4j.properties, so I have these questions to understand how impala logging.

Comment: Impala core is a C/C++ application. What are you trying to use for log4j?